# selected value get from db into dropdown select box option using php mysql error

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get selected value from db into select box. please, tell me how to do it. Here is the code. 
Note: 'options' value depends on the category.

```
<?php 
  $sql = "select * from mine where username = '$user' ";
  $res = mysql_query($sql);
  while($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $category = $list['category'];
    $username = $list['username'];
    $options = $list['options'];
?>

<input type="text" name="category" value="<?php echo '$category' ?>" readonly="readonly" />
<select name="course">
   <option value="0">Please Select Option</option>
   <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
   <option value="ASP">ASP</option>
</select>

<?php 
  }
?>
```

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: please explain your question clearly

Comment: Could you please post your table and dummy data as well?

Comment: Here i need to print Category (which category user submitted along with option select box which option user submitted when posting form). this form is edit form user can see which category and option he selected . if user wants to change option he can do in edit form.

Comment: i have tried as <option value="<?php echo $options ?>>"<?php echo $options ?> </option> but it only prints selected value instead of this i need as i want to show user option value in select box first and second remain option also. but i have no idea how to do.

Comment: @BolemVeeru Did you check my answer below?

Answer (score 41):

I think you are looking for below code changes:

```
<select name="course">
<option value="0">Please Select Option</option>
<option value="PHP" <?php if($options=="PHP") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >PHP</option>
<option value="ASP" <?php if($options=="ASP") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >ASP</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @BolemVeeru If $options from your code contains one of the courses from the drop down for courses, it should work. Can you just print and check the value of $options before the dropdown

Comment: how its done when `select` tag pass into php variable lik `$role= '<select class="form-control" name="role" id="role">
                            <option value="">Select</option>
                            <option value="a" <?php if($admin[0]->role=="Admin") echo selected="selected"; ?>>Admin</option>
                            </select>';`

Comment: Just echo " selected" (note space at beginning) and you'll be fine.

Comment: how to achieve this in for loop? if your data is coming from database

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way I can think of is the following:

```
<?php

$selection = array('PHP', 'ASP');
echo '<select>
      <option value="0">Please Select Option</option>';

foreach ($selection as $selection) {
    $selected = ($options == $selection) ? "selected" : "";
    echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$selection.'">'.$selection.'</option>';
}

echo '</select>';
```

The code basically places all of your options in an array which are called upon in the foreach loop. The loop checks to see if your $options variable matches the current selection it's on, if it's a match then $selected will = selected, if not then it is set as blank. Finally the option tag is returned containing the selection from the array and if that particular selection is equal to your $options variable, it's set as the selected option.

Answer (score 5):

for example ..and please use mysqli() next time because mysql() is deprecated.

```
<?php
$select="select * from tbl_assign where id='".$_GET['uid']."'"; 
$q=mysql_query($select) or die($select);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($q);
?>

<select name="sclient" id="sclient" class="reginput"/>
<option value="">Select Client</option>
<?php $s="select * from tbl_new_user where type='client'";
$q=mysql_query($s) or die($s);
while($rw=mysql_fetch_array($q))
{ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $rw['login_name']; ?>"<?php if($row['clientname']==$rw['login_name']) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?php echo $rw['login_name']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Select value from drop down.

```
<select class="form-control" name="category" id="sel1">
    <?php foreach($data as $key =>$value) { ?>                         
        <option value="<?php echo $data[$key]->name; ?>"<?php if($id_name[0]->p_name==$data[$key]->name) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?php echo $data[$key]->name; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just Add an extra hidden option and print selected value from database

```
<option value="<?php echo $options;?>" hidden><?php echo $options;?></option>
<option value="PHP">PHP</option>
<option value="ASP">ASP</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

### THE EASIEST SOLUTION

It will add an extra  in your options but your problem will be solved.

```
<?php 
    if ($editing == Yes) {
        echo "<option value=\".$MyValue.\" SELECTED>".$MyValue."</option>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$option = $result['semester'];
<option >Select</option>
                    <option value="1st" <?php if($option == "1st") echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>1st</option>
                    <option value="2nd" <?php if($option == "2nd") echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>2nd</option>
                    <option value="3rd" <?php if($option == "3rd") echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>3rd</option>
                    <option value="4th" <?php if($option == "4th") echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>4th</option>
                    <option value="5th" <?php if($option == "5th") echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>5th</option>
                    <option value="6th" <?php if($option == "6th") echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>6th</option>
                    <option value="7th" <?php if($option == "7th") echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>7th</option>
                    <option value="8th" <?php if($option == "8th") echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>8th</option>
                </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

BEST code and simple

```
<select id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple" name="category">

    <?php
    $query = "select * from mine";
    $results = mysql_query($query);

    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc(@$results)){ 
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $rows['category'];?>"><?php echo $rows['category'];?></option>

    <?php
    } 
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this ....

```
<?php  $countryname = $all_meta_for_user['country']; ?>

<select id="mycountry"  name="country" class="user">

    <?php $myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_countries order by country_name" );
    foreach($myrows as $rows){
        if( $countryname == $rows->id ){ 
            echo "<option selected = 'selected' value='".$rows->id."'>".$rows->country_name."</option>";
        } else{ 
            echo "<option value='".$rows->id."'>".$rows->country_name."</option>";
        }
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

**USING PDO**

```
<?php
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "db_name";

$dns = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$db;charset=utf8mb4";
$conn = new PDO($dns,$username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = "select * from mine where username = ? ";

$stmt1 = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt1->execute(array($_POST['user']));
$all = $stmt1->fetchAll(); ?>

<div class="controls">
    <select  data-rel="chosen"  name="degree_id" id="selectError">
        <?php 
        foreach($all as $nt) { 
            echo "<option value =$nt[id]>$nt[name]</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple.
when u pass value from dropdown.

Just use as if else.

for eg:

```
foreach($result as $row) {                      
   $GLOBALS['output'] .='<option value="'.$row["dropdownid"].'"'. 
   ($GLOBALS['passselectedvalueid']==$row["dropwdownid"] ? ' Selected' : '').' 
   >'.$row['valueetc'].'</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
  $sql = "select * from mine where username = '$user' ";
  $res = mysql_query($sql);
  while($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $category = $list['category'];
    $username = $list['username'];
    $options = $list['options'];
?>

<input type="text" name="category" value="<?php echo '$category' ?>" readonly="readonly" />
<select name="course">
<option value="0">Please Select Option</option>
<option value="PHP" <?php echo $options == 'PHP' ? 'selected' : ''; ?> >PHP</option>
<option value="ASP" <?php echo $options == 'ASP' ? 'selected' : ''; ?> >ASP</option>
</select>

<?php 
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [eval()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) PHP function like this:

My PHP code:

```
$selOps1 = $selOps2 = $selOps3 = '';
eval('$selOps'. $dbRow["DBitem"] . ' = "selected";');
```

Then in my select box I use it like this:

```
<select>
   <option <?=$selOps1?> value="1">big</option>
   <option <?=$selOps2?> value="2">Middle</option>
   <option <?=$selOps3?> value="3">Small</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put value from db into a variable and check like following code example

```
<select class="form-control" name="currency_selling" required >
     <option value="">Select Currency</option>
     <option value="pkr" <?=$selected_currency == 'pkr' ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?> >PKR</option>
  <option value="dollar"  <?=$selected_currency == 'dollar' ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?> >USD</option>
  <option value="pounds"  <?=$selected_currency == 'pounds' ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?> >POUNDS</option>
  <option value="dirham"  <?=$selected_currency == 'dirham' ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?> >DRHM</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score -1):

This may help you.

```
?php 
$sql = "select * from mine where username = '$user' ";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
$category = $list['category'];
$username = $list['username'];
$options = $list['options'];
?>
<input type="text" name="category" value="<?php echo '$category' ?>" readonly="readonly" />
<select name="course">
<option value="0">Please Select Option</option>
// Assuming $list['options'] is a coma seperated options string 
$arr=explode(",",$list['options']);
<?php foreach ($arr as $value) { ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
<?php } >
</select>

<?php 
}
?>
```