# Populating a select dropdown with a database value PHP

Tags: html

I am trying to find a clear answer for populating a select option drop down menu with a value from a database. I have found various answers including this one which I thought was what I needed but turned out to not be the case.

[selected value get from db into dropdown select box option using php mysql error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18733545/selected-value-get-from-db-into-dropdown-select-box-option-using-php-mysql-error)

As described in the previous post my question looks like so. I have a form that is populated with all the database values of a current listing. I can get everything to echo correctly except what the user previously selected under status.

A snippet of my form is as follows. MLS # echos back from the saved variable $listingMLS just fine and populates the form perfectly however when I echo $listingStatus which returns the correct value of the current listing it does not update the selected option.

I am sure there is something I am missing and will provide any further descriptions needed. I hope I conveyed this clearly.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
MLS #
<input type="text" maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="listingMLS" value="<?php echo $listingMLS; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
Status
<select class='form-control' name='listingStatus' value="<?php echo $listingStatus; ?>">
<option value='0' selected>Active</option>
<option value='1' selected>Price Reduced</option>
<option value='2' selected>Sold</option>
<option value='3' selected>Archived</option>
</select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You have all 4 options marked with a "selected" attribute

Comment: Thank you, this is one of those minor details that I just glanced over. Still learning :) thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

`value` is not a valid attribute for `<select>` element. 
See docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

You should compare `$listingStatus` inside the loop and then print selected if matched. Something like:

```
<select class='form-control' name='listingStatus'>
<?php
   foreach($DBListing as $listing):
      echo '<option value="'. $listing['status'] .'" '.
         (($listing['status'] == $listingStatus)?'selected="selected"':'')
      .'>'. $listing['title'] .'</option>';
   endforeach;
?>
</select>
```