# Trying to have automatic Selected option depending on my database records

Tags: php, html

Basically I am trying to check what's currently on my database and put it as default option with help of some PHP.
Could you show me a solution how to adjust my code or any alternative for this?

I tried adding select="selected" by PHP

```
<select name="offers" required>
<option value="yes" <?php if($offers=="yes"){?>selected="selected"<?php}?> >yes</option>
<option value="no" <?php if($offers=="no"){?> selected="selected"<?php}?> >no</option>
</select>
```

I just want to make it automatically choose option as selected which is equal to the variable that I get from the database

Comment: Are you creating the checkboxes dynamically ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selected value get from db into dropdown select box option using php mysql error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18733545/selected-value-get-from-db-into-dropdown-select-box-option-using-php-mysql-error)

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need `selected=‘selected’`, just have `selected` as it runs off a Boolean; I.e. selected=true (the option will be selected) or selected=false (default - the option will not be selected). For example;

```
<select name="offers" required>
    <option value="yes" <?php echo $offer=="yes" ? 'selected' : ''; ?> >yes</option>
    <option value="no" <?php echo $offer=="no" ? 'selected' : ''; ?> >no</option>
</select>
```